# Determine which PropertyInfos of a generic TEntity are primary keys via reflection

Tags: mysql, generics, reflection, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am writing a MySQL `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` implementation via a raw SQL command in EF Core 2.0. I am very close to a working solution, but the only problem that I have is determining which PropertyInfos read via reflection are primary keys. In the `CreateUpdates()` method below, how can I filter primary keys out from `columnProperties` so they are not a part of the update SQL statement?

I have tried using [EntityFramework.PrimaryKey](https://github.com/NickStrupat/EntityFramework.PrimaryKey/)
, but I cannot seem to get it to work with generics (`TEntity`).

I have included all of my relevant code, but the piece I am focused on in this question is the `TODO` in the last method, `CreateUpdates()`.

```
private static void InsertOnDuplicateKeyUpdate<TEntity>(DbContext dbContext) where TEntity : class
{
    var columnProperties = GetColumnPropertiesLessBaseEntityTimestamps<TEntity>();
    var tableName = GetTableName<TEntity>();
    var columns = string.Join(", ", columnProperties.Select(x => x.Name));
    var values = CreateValues<TEntity>(columnProperties);
    var updates = CreateUpdates(columnProperties);
    var rawSqlString = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " (" + columns + ") VALUES " + values +
                        " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE " + updates;
    dbContext.Set<TEntity>().FromSql(rawSqlString);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}

private static string GetTableName<TEntity>()
{
    return typeof(TEntity).Name.Pluralize().ToLower();
}

private static List<PropertyInfo> GetColumnPropertiesLessBaseEntityTimestamps<TEntity>()
{
    return typeof(TEntity).GetProperties().Where(x =>
        x.PropertyType.Namespace != "System.Collections.Generic" &&
        !new List<string> {"CreatedDateUtc", "ModifiedDateUtc"}.Contains(x.Name)).ToList();
}

private static string CreateValues<TEntity>(IReadOnlyCollection<PropertyInfo> columnProperties)
{
    return GetSeedRows<TEntity>().Select(row => CreateRowValues(columnProperties, row)).Aggregate("",
        (current, rowValues) => current == "" ? rowValues : current + ", " + rowValues);
}

private static string CreateRowValues<TEntity>(IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> columnProperties, TEntity row)
{
    return (from property in columnProperties
                let value = row.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name).GetValue(row)
                select WrapStringPropertyValueInSingleQuotes(property, value)).Aggregate("",
                (current, value) => current == "" ? "(" + value : current + ", " + value) + ")";
}

private static object WrapStringPropertyValueInSingleQuotes(PropertyInfo property, object value)
{
    if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string))
        value = "'" + value + "'";
    return value;
}

private static string CreateUpdates(IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> columnProperties)
{
    //TODO: filter out primary keys from columnProperties
    return columnProperties.Select(property => property.Name).Aggregate("", (current, column) => current == ""
        ? column + " = VALUES(" + column + ")"
        : current + ", " + column + " = VALUES(" + column + ")");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ef-core it has become much easier to retrieve meta data from the mapping model. You can get the `PropertyInfo`s of the primary key by this line:

```cs
var keyPropertyInfos = dbContext.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(TEntity))
    .FindPrimaryKey()
    .Properties
    .Select(p => p.PropertyInfo);
```

By the way, you can get all (mapped) properties by replacing `FindPrimaryKey().Properties` by `GetProperties()`;

Comment: Wow, thanks! I don't know how my Google-Fu didn't lead me to the `dbContext.Model.FindEntityType()` API. That's slick.